# Show SQL query results in Sharepoint

Tags: sql, sharepoint, clearquest

I support Rational clearquest for my company and have been asked to show some of the data in Sharepoint.

I can query the data in Clearquest no problem (Using Toad) but have no idea about how to go displaying it in Sharepoint.

The data I'm querying contains dates and ideally I'd like to be able display it in a sharepoint calendar but list format would do for the moment.

Can anybody offer advice on even where to start?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst you could do the bare bones approach suggested by Ben there are lots of options that will give you a 'leg up' especially if you are just displaying data.

- Your first look should be at SharePoints Data View Web Part (DVWP). There is a length walkthrough [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120113232123/http://www.lcbridge.nl/vision/2009/dvwp.htm) and some great tutorials by [Laura Rogers](https://web.archive.org/web/20101228024503/http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/05/12/data-view-web-part-the-basics-insert-a-dvwp-on-your-page/)
- Very similar but if you hate SharePoint designer there is [Lighting Tools Data Viewer Web Part](https://lightningtools.com/product/data-viewer-web-part)
- If you are using MOSS you could use the Business Data Catalog (BDC) - [Display business data on a SharePoint site](https://web.archive.org/web/20100601125328/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA102164281033.aspx)
- There are other 3rd party options too that don't require MOSS such as [Layer2's Business Data List Connector (BDLC)](https://www.layer2solutions.com/products/layer2-business-data-list-connector)
- If you have technical resource you could (expanding on approach suggested by Ben) write your own [Reusable SQL Data Viewer Web Part](https://web.archive.org/web/20100415020650/http://vspug.com/sam/2007/11/30/developing-a-reusable-sql-data-viewer-webpart-for-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to develop a sharepoint "feature" such as a webpart.  You could then display retrieve the data from the db and display it however you want.  You would basically be developing a asp.net component/application but with certain restrictions that sharepoint forces on you.  You can read the basic steps [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100505143245/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452873.aspx)